# NUnit and Resharper: showing unit test descriptions

Tags: nunit, resharper

I run my unit tests with Resharper's Test Explorer and I would like to show the descriptions of the unit tests instead of the names of the functions - for which I decorate my unit tests with `NUnit.Framework.DescriptionAttribute`.

I would like to ask if there is a way for me to extend NUnit with NUnit addins in order to accomplish this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display of NUnit tests within Resharper is not handled by NUnit, but by the test adapter that the Resharper team wrote. NUnit makes the description available, so Resharper could display the information if the Resharper test runner was modified.